# How to display multiple images stored in a folder in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am developing a django app which converts pdf to images.I am using `FileField` for this purpose and using `ModelForms`. Once uploaded the `pdf` files will get converted into `.png` and stored in a separate folder. The upload and converting pdf to png works fine but now I want to display the converted images.

I know I can use `url` of the uploaded image to display it but the issue is I am uploading a pdf file and hence cannot use the url to display it. I know how to display an uploaded image using `url` of that image. But I am uploading a pdf file, converting into image and finally storing it into separate folder. So how can I display the images stored? Below is the code I am using:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ClearableFileInput
from app1.models import UserUploadModel

class UserUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    

    class Meta:

        model = UserUploadModel
        fields = ['file']
        widgets = {
            'file' : ClearableFileInput(attrs = {'multiple': True}),
        }
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserUploadModel(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'file_uploads')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from app1.forms import UserUploadForm
from app1.models import UserUploadModel
from app1.convert import convert_file
from app1.transfer import move_dir
import os
from project1 import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
          
            files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            
            f_list = []
            
            if files:
                for i in files:
                    file_instance = UserUploadModel(file = i, user = request.user)
                    file_instance.save()
                    f_list.append(file_instance.file.path)
                
                [convert_file(j) for j in f_list]
                
    
                src_dir = os.getcwd()
                dest_dir = os.path.join(src_dir, 'media/converted_files')          
                move_dir(src_dir, dest_dir, '*.png')                
            
            return redirect('app1-display')
        
    else:
        
        form = UserUploadForm()
    
    return render(request, 'app1/home.html', {'form' : form})


@login_required
def display(request):
    
    images = UserUploadModel.objects.filter(user = request.user)

    context = {
        'images' : images
        }
    
    return render(request, 'app1/display.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
{%extends "app1/base.html"%}
{%block content%}

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {%csrf_token%}
      {{form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

{%endblock content%}
```

**display.html**

```
{%extends "app1/base.html"%}
{%load static%}
{%block content%}

    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
        <h2>User: {{request.user.username}}</h2>
    {%endif%}

    {%if images%}
        {%for i in images%}
            <img src={{ i.file.url }}>
        {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}
    
{%endblock content%}
```

Comment: @Ashkan_Noori This does not answer my question. I am asking how to display pdf files which have been converted to images using Django. The link you have provided is not helpful at all and not related to the quesyion

Comment: @KJ I think you misunderstood me. I do not want to display pdf files on the webpage. I AM converting the pdf files to png and the png files are what I want to display

Comment: @KJ To display images in Django you need the `url` of the image. You can only get the `url` if you upload image by either `FileField` or `ImageField`. But the issue is the app is uploading pdf's and not images and hence even if I get url of the file, it will be the url of the pdf file and not it's equivalent png. So how do I display the images?

Comment: But how do I get the url of the temp-uploaded-001.png file? As I said to display images in Django you need the url and then in the template you display them using `<img src={{file.url}}>`. But if I try to display the converted images using the mentioned method it gives an error saying `file has no attribute url`. This is because django can only get the url of the uploaded file(AFAIK) and not other files which were not uploaded. But kindly correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Bro I dont need help with converting the pdf to png. I am already handling it as I have mentioned in my question. What I want is how do I display the converted image?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach change your model and make a file field for the converted pdf also. After converting save the file to this model field. Then you can get the url of the converted file.

Comment: This sounds interesting. How do I save the converted pdf to the new `FileField`?

Comment: make a converted_file as file field in your model. After converting proces you know your destination path, link it to the new file field. (file.name = new path)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but can you use `PIL` to open the image and then use `Django File Response` to return the image.
`from PIL import Image
from django.http import FileResponse`

def display(request):
images = UserUploadModel.objects.filter(user = request.user)
if images:
image = Image.open(images[0].file.path)
return FileResponse(image, content_type='image/png')